# Why is element-wise multiplication not parallelized numpy

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, cpu, matrix-multiplication

AFAIK, numpy uses many threads to parallelize computation. When I do many matrix multiplications it seems it is parallelizing fine, all 8 cpus are used

```
for i in range(123012930):
    np.random.rand(500,100) @ np.random.rand(100,500)
```

[image: Matrix Multiplication CPU Usage]

However computation is not parallelized when I am doing element wise multiplication

```
for i in range(123012930):
    np.random.rand(500,100) * np.random.rand(100,500).T
```

[image: Element wise multiplication CPU usage]

Why might this be happening?

Comment: Matrix multiplication uses BLAS and other optimized libraries when available.  Elementwise uses numpy's own compiled code with all the broadcasting machinery.  Plus, subtract, max, min and other binary ufunc do the same. It's not as standardized.

Comment: Oh that's a bummer. Thanks for the insights

Comment: Don't confuse `numpy` "vectorization" with many-core parallelization.  In your calls each `@` and `*` may use cores differently (at a very low level), but the `for loop` and `np.random.rand` are all run the same way.  With a `timeit` test, the `*` code is faster.  Also your two calculations aren't doing the same thing; one produces a (500,500) with sum of products on size 100 dimenison.  The other just does elementwise multiplication of (500,100) terms.

Comment: @hpaulj Is it possible to "trick" numpy's `*` to use level 1 BLAS for elementwise operations? It seems such a waste of performance to not use it...